# jQuery gets overridden by external plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery on my website. However, given that Chrome plugins might import a jQuery version of there own in the global scope ($), how do I prevent their jQuery (from a plugin on the client's browser) from overriding my jQuery (the one being originally loaded with the website and the extended functions built on top of it).

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: But isn't noConflict the other way round? I can use noConflict to relinquish the use of $. That is the chrome plugin can continue to use it. But what if I have a huge code base with lots of references to $? It should be the chrome plugin jquery that should relinquish control right?

Comment: @Rahul, right. I would say that a Chrome extension that forces all the pages you load to use `$.noConflict()` is irremediably broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery `jQuery.noConflict()`

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

For More details refer https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: It is more of a hack right to safeguard against plugins that might override jquery, that I reference jQuery as either jQuery or something other than $? But then given the number of plugins out there, doesn't this become a forced standard?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following. [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) for tackling these situations.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script>
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        //your code
    })
</script>
```

Then use you can use `$j` instead of `jQuery` or `$` on the places you need to use jQuery reference. Same can be used if there are multiple versions of jQuery is needed on the page. Just use different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend looking in to jQuery.noConflict, you give $/jQuery a different reference - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```